# Windows Phone claims, that my PhoneGap Build app uses location services

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

According to [my application's `config.xml`](https://github.com/trejder/phonegap-kode-reader/blob/master/config.xml), my application is using five plugins:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.0.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.11" />
<gap:plugin name="com.verso.cordova.clipboard" version="0.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="com.google.cordova.admob" version= "2.7.7" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

and one feature:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
```

There isn't even a tiny trace of localization. But, [according to Windows Phone Store](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kode-reader/6658ee94-66bd-4d12-b378-421aa5a6e1a7), my app is using location services. The same is confirmed, when application is installed -- Windows Phone displays a standard reminder, that all location data gathered by this particular application may be also sent to Microsoft servers for blah, blah... The thing is, that my app is **not** using geolocation.

What can be causing this and how can I fix this? How can I force Windows Phone Store to not confuse users of my application, that it uses location services (which is not true)?

Comment: Have you verified none of the plug-ins require it? I imagine Admob might use it to serve location-specific ads.

Comment: It seems, that you're right. It could be possible, if plugin (AdMob here) is able to later requirements list. This, however, does not explain, why this happens only on Windows Store (location requirement is not added / altered in case of Google Play), but I believe, these are some platform-specific glitches. I think, you may consider forming this as an answer, if you care for rep.